# How to disable and enable SelectBox's options depending on a SelectBox's value?

Tags: javascript, dom

I have 3 *SelectBoxes*.

Their names are, lets say *"a","b","c"*.

And the *options* for all *SelectBoxes* are *"1","2","3"*.

If i choose "1" in *first SelectBox*, "1" will be disabled for *other two SelectBoxes*.

But in *first SelectBox* **if i choose "2" after choosing "1"** , I see **"1" and "2" both are disabled for other SelectBoxes**.. How can I solve it by using *DOM*?

Here is the code I wrote:

```
var source = document.getElementsByName("a")[0];
document.getElementsByName("b")[0].options[source.value].setAttribute("disabled","disabled")
```

This code makes first Select Box's value disabled for the SelectBox named "b".

And I dont want to write code like this. I want to have it as an *array*, and use *Loop*.

```
var target=["a","b","c"]
for (int i=0; i<target.length; i++){
   document.getElementsByName(target[i])[0].options[source.value].setAttribute("disabled","disabled");

}
```

But what if i want to change the value for *first SelectBox*, how to **enable** other value, and **disable** this new value for other Select Boxes?

Answer (score 0):

You can first enable all the options when the value changes and then disable only the ones with matching values.

```js
const a = document.querySelector('select.a');

function disable() {
  document.querySelectorAll('select:not(.a) > option[disabled]').forEach(x => x.disabled = false);
  document.querySelectorAll(`select:not(.a) > option[value="${a.value}"]`).forEach(x => x.disabled = true);
}
disable();
a.addEventListener('change', disable);
```

```html
<select class="a">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
<select class="b">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
<select class="c">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thank you for taking time Sir. This project was made in angular.js by elses.. I am trying to figure out where are the select options... I couldnt find yet . Maybe if i can find where they are, then i may adapt your code into it